# Condition number properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, condition-number

Assuming $A$ is invertible,

I know if $A^{-1} = A^T$, then $cond(A)=1$. Is it true the other way around, as in

If $cond(A)=1$, $A^{-1}=A^T$.

Also, does $cond(A^{-1})$ always equal $cond(A)$?

Comment: What is the definition of condition number you have learned? I think the result follows immediately from the definition.

Comment: I learned condition number as norm of matrix times norm of matrix inverse. Additionally, I also have a secondary definition that states the condition number equals the squareroot of the maximum eigenvalue of A * A^T. This second one is how I determined the initial property I stated in the question, but am unsure if it is an "iff" statement that can be shown both ways

Comment: Do you know the relation between mareix norm and the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: cond is the sqrt of (max eigenvalue of A*A^T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible, then it's easy to check that all eigenvalues are non-zero. Let's enumerate the eigenvalues of $A$ in the following way: $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$, such that
$$|\lambda_1|\geq|\lambda_2|\geq\dots\geq|\lambda_n|>0.$$
Then you can see that the condition number of $A$ is in fact
$$cond(A)=\frac{|\lambda_1|}{|\lambda_n|}.$$
Next, you are going to use the fact that the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are precisely: $\lambda_1^{-1},\lambda_2^{-1},\dots,\lambda_n^{-1}$. 
Finally, you can obtain the relation immediately:
$$cond(A)=cond(A^{-1}).$$

Now if $cond(A)=1$, this means all eigenvalues of $A^TA$ equals $1$ because $A^TA$ is positive definite. Recall that every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, thus we actually have $A^TA=I$.